# How to expand Perl variable in BASH context

Tags: perl, bash

Alright, so the question heading might be a bit confusing. I have replicated my actual problem in below code:

I am creating files with two different IP addresses as a prefix and then I want to list the files only with a particular ip address prefix:

I am creating files with "10.10.10.10" and "11.11.11.11" as prefix and then I want to list files only with the "10.10.10.10" prefix.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $ipaddr1 = '10.10.10.10';
for ( my $counter = 1; $counter < 10; $counter++)
{
    my $filename = $ipaddr1."_".$counter.".txt";
    open (my $fh, ">", $filename) or die "$! \n";
}

my $ipaddr2 = '11.11.11.11';
for ( my $counter = 1; $counter < 10; $counter++)
{
    my $filename = $ipaddr2."_".$counter.".txt";
    open (my $fh, ">", $filename) or die "$! \n";
}
print "Done with creating hte files. \n";

print "Lets print the files with only 10.10.10.10 prefix \n";

for my $var ( `ls -1 $ipaddr1_*` )  ### <<< this is the probelm
{
    print $var;
}
```

**Output**:

```
Global symbol "$ipaddr1_" requires explicit package name at test.pl line 21.
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

So, I fully understand the error that it is not able to interpret the perl variable while executing a bash command.

**Question**:

how to achieve this? I do not want to pass explicit IP address to the `ls -1` command but instead want to pass the variable which holds the respective IP address.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest using another approach, [File::Glob](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Glob). Explicitly or via the angle-bracket operator, `<>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**

```
my $cmd = "ls -1 ". $ipaddr1."_*.txt";
for my $var ( `$cmd` )
{
    print $var;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Perl interprets the underscore `_` as part of the variable name.  The most straightforward solution is to add disambiguating brackets so that this won't happen:

```
`ls -1 ${ipaddr1}_*`
```

Answer (score 2):

The `${ipaddr1}_` syntax given by Ilmari Karonen is the correct solution. There are a few other things that might be improved:

1. Don't start a new process for something Perl can already do:

   ```
   for my file (glob "${ipaddr1}_*") {
     print "$file\n";
   }
   ```

   This is also more portable :)
2. Be aware that `open my $fh, ">", $filename` will clobber the file. If you only want to create non-existing files but don't want to clobber the content, use the `>>` append mode instead.
3. Make your life easy and your code short! Use loops and ranges:

   ```
   for my $ipaddr ("10.10.10.10", "11.11.11.11") {
     for my $counter (1 .. 9) {
       my $filename = sprintf "%s_%d.txt", $ipaddr, $counter;
       open my $fh, ">", $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
     }
   }
   ```